# How To Verify Firebase Auth Token Without Client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

So I have been looking around but haven't been able to find anything on this subject. I am trying to authenticate in cloud run, using Firebase completely on the server side.

So my flow will look something like this:

- User will pass in their secret key that we create on our side and
  store in FireStore.
- After doing this we will check to see if the secret key is correct on
  the server and pass the user a firebase token.
- The user will then be able to call any of the endpoints and when they
  hit the function:

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)

  it will check if that users is able to call that endpoint or not using the session token that firebase provides.

I have tried to achieve this with:

```
    admin.auth()
        .createCustomToken(uid)
        .then((customToken) => {
            console.log(customToken)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
        });
```

But creating a custom token requires the end user to have firebase installed on the client side, which is not an option since these will be external users/businesses and most of the calls will be coming from another server.

So, in case its not very clear, what Im trying to achieve is something similar to 3 legged oAuth that Stripe and other API's use, but Im trying to do it with Firebase so that I don't have to stand up my own custom token minting system.

Can someone please help me along with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Edit:

I found a way to do this by doing the following:

```
admin.auth()
    .createCustomToken(uid)
    .then((customToken) => {
        console.log(customToken)

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=XXX', {
            "returnSecureToken": true,
            "token": customToken
        }).then((res) => {
           // My Token Will Now Work In Any Subsequent Calls To Cloud Run
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
    });
```

And then for each protected endpoint I can do the following:

```
const verifiedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
```

Comment: Wrong approach. Google Cloud Run uses IAP for authorization. That means you must put all your users into Google Cloud IAM. Instead, the user should auth with your backend code and your backend makes requests to Cloud Run on behalf of the user using an Identity Token created from a service account.

Comment: My backend is cloud run. So how would I set up another backend "user should auth with your backend code and your backend makes requests to Cloud Run". On top of that wouldn't that make it difficult to manage users if they are not in Identity Platform? This is not for internal users, its for External users. I could see using IAM for internal users, but we are talking a couple hundred companies, with multiple users for each company.

Comment: Also my plan was to use tenants to set up companies and then have each user fall under that tenant that belongs to said company

Comment: One last thing, I see what your saying now but it still doesn't really work to well for my use case. I would rather not use Cloud Endpoints, so I am about to edit my question to show a potential flow. Can you let me know if you see any vulnerabilities in what I want to do.

Comment: You are using various terms without a clear definition of those terms as they mean many things depending on the context. Edit your post and incorporate your last two comments with better clarity.

Comment: Note: I did not mention Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Just a heads up. In certain cases, Google will destroy the signature of an OIDC Identity Token so that it cannot be verified. This is to prevent ID Token Impersonation. However, I do not know if that could apply to your design as I don't have enough details. Just make a note of this in case you run into corrupt signatures.

Comment: Sorry if I was assuming, that was the first thing that popped in my mind when you mentioned another backend. I did edit my answer to show what I could potentially do that is working as of now. If you see that it may be vulnerable please let me know. Essentially what the user would initially be verifying with is their secret key and userID that we have stored in firestore

Comment: Thanks. But as far as security is concerned do you think this may work? If we do run into any problems it could always be changed. We are just trying to get a decent MVP out right now